# How to run specified several android unit-test classes in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, unit-testing, class

We can specify which Android test classes to run in adb mode by the command

> "adb shell am instrument -w -e class
>   TestCase1,TestCase2/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"

Can I do the same thing(**choose several test classes to run**) just by Eclipse's UI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe late... but searching I found the solution:

- Click on run configurations.
- Select in left panel "Launch Group"
- Afterwards select one by one each test you want to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can run them together by including them in the Same Android Test Project.